# Scanner.nextBigInteger(int radix)

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

Why does this code:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {    
   String s = "23 Hello World! 3 + 3.0 = 6 ";    
   // create a new scanner with the specified String Object
   Scanner scanner = new Scanner(s);    
   // scan next token as a Big Integer with radix 4    
   System.out.println("" + scanner.nextBigInteger(4));
   // close the scanner   
   scanner.close();    
}
```

output **11**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It reads the first token in the string `23` as a number in base 4. So the value is 2 * 4 + 3 = 11 which is then printed as the result.

Comment: When I give token in the string 11 as a number in base 37 it throws an exception Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException but I have import util package ?

Comment: Hard to guess what you did exactly. Make it a new question and show the exact code.

Comment: package progams;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class G {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
                String s="11";
  Scanner scanner=new Scanner(s);
  System.out.println(""+scanner.nextBigInteger(37));
  scanner.close();
}
This is my code give output - 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 37

Comment: Radix can be at most 36. The digits used are then 0-9 and the letters a-z. Unfortunately, the error message is not very helpful if you use a radix that is too high.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable answer.